# ¿Cómo imprimir el valor real usando Checkbox en PHP?

Tags: php, checkbox

Necesito hacer un catalogo de productos en PHP, les estoy asignando su valor con value="" en el formulario, pero al seleccionar los checkbox y darle en enviar me da un total a pagar de la cantidad de checkbox que haya seleccionado[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aquí seleccione tres checkbox y me da esto

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aclaro que si quito el `isset` de mi código, me arroja el error `undefined array key`

Espero respuesta, muchas gracias

Comment: Compartenos el codigo y no una imagenen para poderte ayudar mejor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Te está dando como resultado la cantidad de "true" que está encontrando porque se lo estas diciendo así:

```
$pan = isset($_POST['pan']);
```

Es decir, en la línea anterior tan solo le preguntas si está establecida esa variable, a lo que te responde **"true"** (o **"1"**) si es cierto, o **"false"** (o **"0"**) si es falso.  Por eso te suma 3.

Lo que deberias hacer es hacer esa comprobación pero luego asignarle el valor pasado por POST con esto:

```
$pan = isset($_POST['pan']) ? $_POST['pan'] : 0;
```

De este modo, si ese $_POST está establecido, le asignas su valor a la variable, y en caso contrario le asignas el valor de 0.

Si no comprendes esa instrucción revisa cómo usar [operadores ternarios en la documentación de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary).

Comment: Tu respuesta me ha funcionado completamente, muchisimas gracias

Comment: Me alegro :-)  Dos cosas a comentar: 1) Nunca hagas preguntas con imagénes de código, ponlo directamente con copiar/pegar porque sino nos cuesta mucho reproducir tu escenario si tenemos que teclearlo nosotros, gracias. y 2) Si esta respuesta es válida para tu pregunta deberías aceptarla para que no quede pendiente para siempre. En este [enlace](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/428/263200) aprenderás a aceptar respuestas, gracias!

Comment: Gracias por tu recomendación ya se para la próxima, soy nuevo en Stackoverflow ahí voy aprendiendo

Comment: Bienvenido pues!  También para la proxima haz el [tour] (son dos minutejos de tu vida y así aprenderás lo básico del sitio y ganarás tu primera medalla!), y si vuelves a preguntar revisa también [ask] (perdona por los deberes, se lo decimos siempre a los nuevos) y [example].